# How to get the struct value from another class?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to fetch the offerApplied value from the struct in another class. Here is the struct block:

```
struct Offer: JsonDeserilizer {

var offerDesC:String = ""
var discount:Double = 0.0
var offerId:String = ""
var offerCode:String = ""
var offerApplied:Int = 0

mutating func deserilize(values: Dictionary<String, Any>?) {
    self.offerDesC = values?["offer_desc"] as? String ?? ""
    self.discount = values?["discount"] as? Double ?? 0.0
    self.offerId = values?["_id"] as? String ?? ""
    self.offerCode = values?["offer_code"] as? String ?? ""
    self.offerApplied = values?["is_applied"] as? Int ?? 0
}}
```

And an explanation will be very helpful.

Comment: Exactly what is the problem, this sounds like a trivial task so maybe I have misunderstood something. Could you share some of code where you want to access the value or add more context otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `getter` function in your `struct`, that can return specific value as you want. In target class `initialise` your  `struct` properties (by calling deserilize(), or however you wish) and call the `getter` function to fetch values.

**Update-:**

As @Joakim mentioned, your properties are not private, so there is no need to create getter function. You could infact directly refer the property from created object.

```
 struct Offer {
        
        var offerDesC:String = ""
        var discount:Double = 0.0
        var offerId:String = ""
        var offerCode:String = ""
        var offerApplied:Int = 0
        
        mutating func deserilize() {
            self.offerDesC = "xy"
            self.discount = 20
            self.offerId = "okkk"
            self.offerCode = "12"
            self.offerApplied = 245
        }

//    func returnOfferApplied() -> Int{
//        return offerApplied
//    }
        
    }
    
    class xyz{
       var obj = Offer()
        func printOffer(){
            obj.deserilize()
            print(obj.offerApplied)
        }
    }
    
    let obj = xyz()
    obj.printOffer()
```

Comment: There is absolutely no need for a getter method since the property is *not* declared private.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson That’s a valid point, didn’t clicked my mind,Thank you.We can directly refer the property from created object as well.

Answer (score 0):

First create struct class at global file.

Look in my example

```
struct ColorPalette {
    static let UEMColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "72279C")
    static let uemIconPrimary = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "282D68")
}
```

Access Struct Like this:

```
ColorPalette.uemIconPrimary
```

Comment: can'i just grab the value without creating any other struct ?